# Using filter for count annotation with Djongo

Tags: django, sql-parser, djongo

Currently I'm using Django and a MongoDB configured with Djongo.

These are my 2 classes:

```
class Machine (models.Model):
machine_type = models.ForeignKey(MachineType, related_name ='machine_types', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
machine_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='machine_customers', on_delete = 
models.CASCADE)
machine_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
#
def __str__(self):
    return self.machine_serial_number

class Part (models.Model):
part_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
machine_serial_number = models.ForeignKey(Machine, related_name='parts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
machining_start = models.DateTimeField()
machining_end = models.DateTimeField()
quality = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
#
def __str__(self):
    return self.part_id
```

I've been trying to perform the following query to find the number of not OK parts produced on each machine.

```
results=Machine.objects.values('machine_serial_number')
.annotate(part_nok=Count('parts', filter=Q(parts__quality__icontains='NIO')))
```

But I keep receiving the following error message:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN "eda_main_part"."quality" iLIKE %(0)s THEN "eda_main_part"."id" ELSE NULL END) AS 
"part_nok" FROM "eda_main_machine" LEFT OUTER JOIN "eda_main_part" ON ("eda_main_machine"."id" = 
"eda_main_part"."machine_serial_number_id") GROUP BY "eda_main_machine"."machine_serial_number"  
LIMIT 21
Version: 1.2.31
```

Ideally I would like to receive something like:

```
{machine1:#111222, part_nok:121, part_ok:68, ... and so on }
```

When instead performing the following query by leaving out the filter

```
results=Machine.objects
.values('machine_serial_number').annotate(part_nok=Count( 'parts'))
```

everything runs as expected.

I'm usung following tools:

```
sqlparse==0.2.4
djongo==1.2.31
Django==2.2.6
python 3.7.4
MongoDb 4.2
```

Comment: What if you use `part_nok=Count('parts', filter=Q(parts__quality__ixact='NIO'))`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I think you ment iexact. I've also tried this approach but the results seem to be the same.
`results=Machine.objects.values('machine_serial_number').annotate(part_nok=Count('parts', filter=Q(parts__quality__iexact='NIO')))`

Comment: and I get:
`djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: SELECT "eda_main_machine"."machine_serial_number", COUNT(CASE WHEN "eda_main_part"."quality" iLIKE %(0)s THEN "eda_main_part"."id" ELSE NULL END) AS "part_nok" FROM "eda_main_machine" LEFT OUTER JOIN "eda_main_part" ON ("eda_main_machine"."id" = "eda_main_part"."machine_serial_number_id") GROUP BY "eda_main_machine"."machine_serial_number"  LIMIT 21
Version: 1.2.31`

Comment: Do annotations work with djongo at all? I know they are meant to but event the simplest examples from Django tutorial just don't work. Things like ppl = Person.objects.annotate(next_year_age=F('age') + 1); print ppl[0].next_year_age won't work for me :/

Comment: @fanny I didn't get them to work at all with djongo. This is why I changed the database. It's a pity but I couldn't think of something better.

Comment: @GolanuDelamare, neither have I,luckily, hitherto I am able to get a filtered, quite small queryset and can just to what i need to working on that queryset